# Importing certificate into a keystore on Android

Tags: android, ssl, keystore

I have a question about keystore.

Do android have a build in keystore?

If yes, where is the keystore?

Can I import my certificate into the keystore?

If yes, how can I do it manually and programmatically?

Please help, I have struggled with the SSLHandShakeException for a week.

I have used the keytool to generate a new keystore.bks and inserted the my certificate into it but I didn't know how can I use it for my android application.

I also tried the code that I have found online.

In MyHttpsClient.java

```
public class MyHttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient{

final Context context;

public MyHttpsClient(Context context) {
    System.out.println("context client http");
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager(){
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    System.out.println("schema");
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 8080));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
}

private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory(){
    try{
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        System.out.println("context client getInstance..");
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
        System.out.println("context client input" + in);
        try{
        System.out.println("try");
            trusted.load(in, "changeit".toCharArray());
        }finally{
            in.close();
        }
        System.out.println("finally");
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sf;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
}
```

In my Main.java

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpsClient(getApplicationContext());
```

I have the code above in the onCreate() of my Main.java, but I have no idea why it doesn't go into my @Override function in MyHttpsClient.java

Can I read the original android emulator keystore and put the certificate into the keystore?

Comment: Do you need keystore to sign your apk?

Comment: not yet, because what I need is to connect to the https server

Comment: @ShayanKM The question is about SSL handshake exceptions, not signing APKs.

Comment: @EJP any recommendation for me because I am so lost now.

Comment: so check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL

Comment: Hi @ShayanKM I have gone through the article but I don't know where should I implement the code. Something like should I open a new class or create a function or implement in the main activity?

Comment: If the server you connect to is fixed (determined by your code not by the user) you should prepare the keystore on your PC and only use it within your app. BTW: keytool is only for masochists or special use cases. The other use Portecle graphical program.